# $_POST и массив

Tags: php

Вот форма:

```
<form action="/test">
    <input type="text" name="text1">
    <input type="text" name="text2">
    <input type="text" name="text3">
    <input type="submit" name="do_send" value="Send">
</form>
```

Итак, если я вар дампну $_POST, я получу массив вида:

```
array(3) {
  ["text1"] => string(5) "Text1"
  ["text2"] => string(5) "Text2"
  ["text3"] => string(5) "Text3"
}
```

У меня есть массив:

```
$arr = array('text1','text3');
```

Как мне вытянуть ключи таким образом, чтобы из $_POST отфильтровался ключ 'text2' ибо он не нужен?

То есть в форме 3 инпута а после валидации у меня получилось всего два ключа?

```
array(2) {
  ["text1"] => string(5) "Text1"
  ["text3"] => string(5) "Text3"
}
```

Я хочу упростить себе жизнь и сделать маленькую валидацию, а не писать тонны мусорного кода для проверки.

Поможете?

Дополняю:
$_POST - это и есть $_POST['text1'] и тд...

```
public function getEditMain() {
    $smarty = $this->loadsmarty();
    $this->ValidAdmin();
    $data = $_POST;

    $mtype = current(R::getAssoc('SELECT type FROM `mainconfigs`'));
    $mtitle = current(R::getAssoc('SELECT title FROM `mainconfigs`'));
    $mtemplate = current(R::getAssoc('SELECT template FROM `mainconfigs`'));
    $metarobots = current(R::getAssoc('SELECT meta_robots FROM `mainconfigs`'));
    $metatitle = current(R::getAssoc('SELECT meta_og_title FROM `mainconfigs`'));
    $metadescr = current(R::getAssoc('SELECT meta_og_descr FROM `mainconfigs`'));
    $metakeys = current(R::getAssoc('SELECT meta_og_keys FROM `mainconfigs`'));
    $metaurl = current(R::getAssoc('SELECT meta_og_url FROM `mainconfigs`'));
    $metaimg = current(R::getAssoc('SELECT meta_og_img FROM `mainconfigs`'));
    $metatype = current(R::getAssoc('SELECT meta_og_type FROM `mainconfigs`'));

    $smarty->assign('title',$mtitle);
    $smarty->assign('meta_og_title',$mtitle);
    $smarty->assign('template',$mtemplate);
    $smarty->assign('meta_og_title',$metatitle);
    $smarty->assign('meta_og_descr',$metadescr);
    $smarty->assign('meta_og_keys',$metakeys);
    $smarty->assign('meta_og_url',$metaurl);
    $smarty->assign('meta_og_img',$metaimg);
    $smarty->assign('meta_og_type',$metatype);

    if ($mtype) {
        $smarty->assign('editmainstatus',$mtype);
    }
    if ($metarobots == 'index,follow') {
        $smarty->assign('metaindex1','checked="checked"');
    } else if  ($metarobots == 'index,nofollow') {
        $smarty->assign('metaindex2','checked="checked"');
    } else if  ($metarobots == 'noindex,nofollow') {
        $smarty->assign('metaindex3','checked="checked"');
    }

    if (isset($data['main_config'])) {
        $arrs = array('title','meta_og_title','meta_og_descr','meta_og_keys','meta_og_url','meta_og_img','meta_og_type');
        var_dump(array_intersect($data, array_flip($arrs))); // У меня помимо полей есть ещё много мусорных элементов, как мне их отфильтровать? array(1) { ["radio"]=> string(1) "1" }
        exit;
    }

    $smarty->assign('module','admin/mainedit.tpl');
    $smarty->assign('configsArray',$table);
    return $smarty->display('admin/html.tpl');
}
```

Comment: Поможем, только для начала покажите нам, что вы уже делали, и что из этого получилось, и что не получилось, ок?

Comment: @misdeed, дополнил

Comment: Про массив с ошибками наверное стоит в новый вопрос и более подробно расписать что хотите и что имеется.

Comment: Как-то плохо вы редактируете постоянно вопрос, а нам подстраиваться. Что опять не так? Покажите $data и что вас не устраивает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Моя версия:

```
$a = array('text1' => 11, 'text2' => 22, 'text3' => 33);
$b = array('text1', 'text2');

var_dump(array_intersect_key($a, array_flip($b)));
```

Comment: Чутка опередили... :)

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов не спать :D

Comment: @Manitikyl Выводит не то что нужно :( Дополнил вопрос

Comment: @MrMEX Покажите $data и что вас не устраивает.

Comment: @Manitikyl https://i.imgur.com/zDylDWu.png

Comment: @MrMEX перед `exit;` Сделайте `var_dump($data);` и покажите что вывело, так понятней будет.

Comment: @Manitikyl https://pastebin.com/5w668nuR

Comment: @MrMEX К сожалению вы взяли не мой ответ, а предыдущий, из-за этого у вас ошибка: У вас сейчас `array_intersect` а надо `array_intersect_key`

Answer (score 1):

Например, воспользоваться функцией: [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-uintersect.php):

```
$_POST = array(
    'text1' => 'text1',
    'text2' => 'text2',
    'text3' => 'text3',
    'text4' => 'text4'
);
$arr = array('text1', 'text3');
var_dump(array_intersect($_POST, $arr));
```

Вернет:

```
array(2) { 
    ["text1"]=> string(5) "text1" 
    ["text3"]=> string(5) "text3" 
}
```

https://repl.it/repls/BonyDecentPercent

Для сравнения по ключам, можно воспользоваться функцией [`array_intersect_key`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-intersect-key.php) и поменять местами ключи и значения 2-го массива с помощью функции[`array_flip`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-flip.php):

```
var_dump(array_intersect_key($_POST, array_flip($arr)));
```

Вывод:

```
array(2) { 
    ["text1"]=> string(5) "text1" 
    ["text3"]=> string(5) "text3" 
}
```

Comment: Неудачный ответ, у вас идет сравнение по значениям, а автору требуется ключ-значение. У него первый массив ассоциативный.

Comment: @Manitikyl, сначала документацию по функции почитайте.

Comment: я и так знаю что делает, а теперь возьмите и переделайте массив: `'text1' => 'text1',` в `'text1' => 'text11',` и сравните результаты.

Comment: @Manitikyl. ну тогда поменять местами и все, а потом снова поменять.

Comment: Так дайте корректный* ответ ;)

Comment: @And, у меня такое выдаёт пустой массив после отправки поста.